# How to store the database instance in a helper class?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I'm trying to use sqflite with flutter. For now, all I want is to make a helper class that can handle the connection to the database. (I do not want to run a query from within that class)

I have the following code:

```
//SQL dependencies
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  static Database _db;

  connect() async {
    // Avoid errors caused by flutter upgrade.
    // Importing 'package:flutter/widgets.dart' is required.
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
    // Open the database and store the reference.
    // Note:Using the `join` function from the `path` package is best practice to ensure the 
    // path is correctly constructed for each platform.
    var pathToDB = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'notebook_database.db');

    _db = await openDatabase(
        pathToDB,
        version: 1
    );
  }

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    
    _db = await connect();
    return _db;
  }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error at the line "static Database _db", which tells me "Non nullable variable must be initialized"

What is the correct approach to store the database instance in a class?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of outdated code out there, including the code from the documentation which lacks ffi, which give an error on the call to getDatabasesPath()...

I found the following implementation that seems to work for me:

in pubspec.yaml, add the sqflite_common_ffi dependency:

```
dependencies:
  sqflite_common_ffi: any
```

in /lib/main.dart, add the following import and 2 lines for FfI:

```
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart'; 

void main() {

  // Add those 2 lines in main(), before runApp.
  // Initialize FfI for the database
  sqfliteFfiInit();
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;

  runApp(const MyApp());

}
```

Create /lib/database/database_service.dart:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import 'package:my_app/database/note_db.dart'; //Required by the create method.

class DatabaseService {
  Database? _database;

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if(_database != null) {
      return _database!;
    }

    _database = await _initialize();
    return _database!;
  }

  Future<Database> _initialize() async{

    // Avoid errors caused by flutter upgrade.
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // 'package:flutter/widgets.dart'

    var database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'notes.db'),
      version:1,
      onCreate: create,
      singleInstance: true,
    );
    return database;
  }

  Future<void> create(Database database, int version) async => 
    await NoteDB().createTable(database); //Create a new table
}
```

Example of usage, by creating a class that handle the CRUD (/lib/database/note_db.dart):

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:my_app/database/database_service.dart';

class NoteDB{
  final tableName = 'notes';

  Future<void> createTable(Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tableName (
      "id" INTEGER,
      "title" TEXT,
      "content" TEXT,
      "createdAt INTEGER,
      "updatedAt INTEGER,
      PRIMARY KEY ("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
      );""");
    
  }
  
  Future<int> create({required String title}) async {
    final database = await DatabaseService().database;
    return await database.rawInsert(
      '''INSERT INTO $tableName (title, createdAt) VALUES (?,?)''',
      [title, DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch],
    );
  }
  
  // ...
  
}
```